# Error in table(data[, tgt]) : attempt to set an attribute on NULL when using SMOTE

Tags: r

My data.frame(train) is having 12162 records and 34 predictors , 1 target , 1 primary key(ID).
I am applying smote for this data .

```
library(DMwR)
smote_data <- SMOTE(as.factor(train$POSSIBLE_FRAUD) ~ ., 
                    data=train, perc.over=400, perc.under=100)
```

For this i am getting the below error.

```
Error in table(data[, tgt]) : attempt to set an attribute on NULL
```

Pls help me what is the possibility for this error

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example

Comment: Problem got solved. There was a space in my target column name at the end .. So used  names(train)<- trim(names(train))